# Login and password validation NodeJS

Tags: json, node.js, webix

I'm a beginner , trying  to make a login form with Webix and NodeJS.

When the post request comes to the server , the server compares request data and data from .json file and should write 'OK' in the console when there are  same login and password.

The problem is that it writes 'ok' even when the password or login is from another user. So i can write login from one user and password from another and it will give me a possitive answer.

How to make it search login and password from one json Object?
Code :

```
if (login == "login") {
            fs.readFile("JSON/DB.json", "utf8", function (err, data) {

                //console.log(data);


                var jsonFileArr = []; // Array with .json objects                   
                jsonFileArr = JSON.parse(data);


                var gotLog = jsonFileArr.some(function (obj) {
                    /* Searches for the same login*/
                    return obj.log == loginData.log;
                })

                var gotPass = jsonFileArr.some(function (obj) {
                    /* Searches for the same password */
                    return obj.pass == loginData.pass;
                })

                if (gotLog && gotPass) {
                    console.log("OK");
                }
                else
                    console.log("Wrong login or password");

            });
        }
        else {
            console.log("Error");
        }
```

JSON : http://myjson.com/21rvm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem more logical to me to first match on username and then check the appropriate password. Especially if you consider encrypting it.

This is not a direct answer but here is an example of a similar thing I wrote a while back:

```
server.post('/auth/login', function(req,res) {
const username = req.body.username;
const password = req.body.password;
if(testEmail(username)){
  dataFacade.getUser({'username' : username}, function(user) {
    if (user) {
      if (bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
        req.login({'id': user._id, 'username': user.username, 'permission': user.permission}, function(err) {
          if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send(err);
          } else {
            res.cookie('user', user, cookieParams);
            return res.status(200).send(user);
          }
        });
      } else {
        return res.status(401).send('notAllowed');
      }
    } else {
      return res.status(400).send('notFound');
    }
  });
} else {
  return res.status(401).send('notAllowed');
}
```

}
);

So there are three layers to this:

1. Testing to see if the username is a valid username (You can use the same regex as you're using on the front-end)
2. Seeing if that username already exists
3. Matching the password, preferably encrypted

I used a data facade to retrieve the data between, but you can do the same with loops seeing as your not using a database it seems. Though I highly recommend you store it in a database of some sort.

Comment: I know that database is better and i should use it , but right now i'm just starting to learn. Also right now i'm not thinking about encrypting password , that is my future ))

Comment: Oh and thanks for pointing out the layers. It makes easier to understand the logic behind it.